# Linear equation in two variables

Tags: word-problem

The denominator of a fraction is 4 more than twice the numerator. When both the denominator & numerator are decreased by 6, then the denominator becomes 12 times the numerator .determine the fraction.

I tried to solve the sum but my answer is coming as 1/22 but the answer should be 7/18. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Let the fraction be $\frac{x}{y}$. By the given condition you have two equations: $$y=2x+4$$ and $$y-6=12(x-6).$$ Solve for $x$ and $y$ from these two equations.